# How to create an Order Model with a type field that dictates other fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, architecture

I'm building a Ruby on Rails App for a business and will be utilizing an ActiveRecord database. My question really has to do with Database Architecture and really the best way I should organize all the different tables and models within my app. So the App I'm building is going to have a database of orders for an ECommerce Business that sells products through 2 different channels, a subscription service where they pick the products and sell it for a fixed monthly fee and a traditional ECommerce channel, where customers pay for their products directly. So essentially while all of these would be classified as the Order model, there are two types of Orders: Subscription Order and Regular Order.

So initially I thought I would classify all this activity in my Orders Table and include a field 'Type' that would indicate whether it is a subscription order or a regular order. My issue is that there are a bunch of fields that I would need that would be specific to each type. For instance, transaction_id, batch_id and sub_id are all fields that would only be present if that order type was a subscription, and conversely would be absent if the order type was regular.

My question is, would it be in my best interest to just create two separate tables, one for subscription orders and one for regular orders? Or is there a way that fields could only appear conditional on what the Type field is? I would hate to see so many Nil values, for instance, if the order type was a regular order.

Sorry this question isn't as technical as it is just pertaining to best practice and organization.

Thanks,
Sunny

Comment: As a side note, avoid naming any of your fields 'type'. ActiveRecord will throw a fit.

Answer (score 2):

What you've described is a pattern called [Single Table Inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Single+table+inheritance) — aka, having one table store data for different types of objects with different behavior.

Generally, people will tell you not to do it, since it leads to a lot of empty fields in your database which will hurt performance long term. It also just looks gross.

You should probably instead store the data in separate tables. If you want to get fancy, you can try to implement Class Table Inheritance, in which there are actually separate but connected table for each of the child classes. This isn't supported natively by ActiveRecord. [This gem](https://github.com/brunofrank/class-table-inheritance) and [this gem](https://github.com/hzamani/acts_as_relation/) might be able to help you, but I've never used either, so I can't give you a firm recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep all of my orders in one table. You could create a second table for "subscription order information" that would only contain the columns transaction_id, batch_id and sub_id as well as a primary key to link it back to the main orders table. You would still want to include an order type column in the main database though to make it a little easier when debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Postgres, I might lean towards an Hstore for that.

Some reading:

http://www.devmynd.com/blog/2013-3-single-table-inheritance-hstore-lovely-combination

https://github.com/devmynd/hstore_accessor

Answer (score 0):

Make an integer column called order_type.

In the model do:

SUBSCRIPTION = 0

ONLINE = 1

...

It'll query better than strings and whenever you want to call one you do Order:SUBSCRIPTION.
Make two+ other tables with a foreign key equal to whatever the ID of the corresponding row in orders.

Now you can keep all shared data in the orders table, for easy querying, and all unique data in the other tables so you don't have bloated models.